# Adding Custom Post Types to category/tag/author archives breaks header content

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives

I'm using the following code in functions.php to add Custom Post Type content to my Category, Tag and Author archives:

```
// Add New Custom Post Types to Archives

function rtt_add_cpts_to_archives( $query ) {

    if( is_category() || is_tag() || is_author() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'work', 'event', 'news', 'newsletter' ) );

        return $query;

    }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'rtt_add_cpts_to_archives' );
```

But am having a problem with the site's header when I do, and can't figure out why.

From everything I've read online, this code should work as is.

However, without 'nav_menu_item' added above my header content comes back completely blank. No site logo, no menu and no h5 tagline.

By adding 'nav_menu_item' I get the menu back, but the logo and tagline are still missing.

If I comment out this code they come back.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You don’t check if it’s is_main_query, so your code modifies all queries on site (wp_nav_menu uses WP_Query too, and many other functions do).

Comment: Holy mother of... @KrzysiekDróżdż - you absolutely RULE!

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted like that, recognized sites like https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/ are showing this code in a way they will break other parts of the page. Thanks for the answer, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The amazing @Krzysiek Dróżdż was right on the money on this one!

I can't believe nobody has picked it up until now.

The code I was using has been shared on all sorts of well-known/well-referenced sites, as is, and NOBODY has fixed it to include is_main_query.

Revised code, for anybody else who's searching:

```
// Add New Custom Post Types to Archives

function rtt_add_cpts_to_archives( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_category() || is_tag() || is_author() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'work', 'event', 'news', 'newsletter' ) );

        return $query;

    }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'rtt_add_cpts_to_archives' );
```